# send and receive the request in snake casing in asp.net web api

Tags: asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, json.net

The variables used in the *CaseClass* are converted into snake casing while sending the request, but it needs to be converted from snake casing and needs to bind with the variables in *CaseClass* by default while receiving the request.

Request sender code

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
var caseClass = new CaseClass
{
    FirstName = "xxx",
    LastName = "y"
};

using (var proxy = new CustomWebClient())
{
    var ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(CaseClass));
    var mem = new MemoryStream();
    ser.WriteObject(mem, CaseClass);
    proxy.Headers["Content-type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    proxy.Headers["Authorization"] = token.token_type + " " + token.access_token;
    proxy.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
    var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(mem.ToArray(), 0, (int)mem.Length);

    try
    {
        var rdata = proxy.UploadString(new Uri("http://localhost:56612/api/v1.0/users/"), "POST", data);
        var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ItemResponse>(rdata);

    }
    catch (WebException ex)
    {
        if (ex.Response is HttpWebResponse)
        {
            var resp = new StreamReader(ex.Response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();

            dynamic obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(resp);
            Console.WriteLine(obj);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

}

```
[Serializable]
[DataContract]
public class CaseClass
{
    [DataMember(Name = "first_name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "last_name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Post method receiving the request

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/v1.0/users")]
    public void TestMethod(CaseClass caseClass)
    {
        //processing the request
    }
```

So while sending the request the *CaseClass* members need to be converted to snake casing and while receiving the request the *CaseClass* members need to be converted from snake casing.

> Note: I am not using only CaseClass, the conversion needs to be done generally for all classes.

Comment: Which part of your code doesn't work?

Comment: Code is working properly and the variables used in the *CaseClass* are converted into snake casing while sending the request, but it needs to be converted from snake casing and needs to bind with the variables in *CaseClass* by default while receiving the request.